# responseSerializationFailed with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var urlTextFiled: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextFiled: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextFiled: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

        guard let email = emailTextFiled.text, !email.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        guard let password = passwordTextFiled.text, !password.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        let db = "mohanad"
        let url = "http://176.58.117.249/web/session/authenticate"

        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "db": db,
        "login": email,
        "password": password ,
        ]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<600)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result
            {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

            case .success(let value):

                print(value)
            }

        }


    }

}
```

prints the following error:

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"call","params":{"db":"mohanad","login":"mohanad@amana.ps","password":"mohanad123"}}

Comment: your server sends me this response `Bad Request`. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Paramters:

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "jsonrpc":"2.0",
        "method":"call",
        "params": [
            "db": db,
            "login": "mohanad@amana‌​.ps",
            "password": "moh‌​anad123",
            ]
        ]
```

request. use a `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`, because you have pass Raw value.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<600)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result
            {
            case .failure(let error):
                if let data = response.data {
                    print("Print Server Error: " + String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                }
                print(error)

            case .success(let value):

                print(value)
            }

    }
```

your api give me this type of data in this

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Session expired (invalid CSRF token)</p>\n"
```

Comment: Print Server Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Invalid JSON data: 'db=mohanad&amp;login=mohanad%40amana.ps&amp;password=mohanad123'</p>

responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: Try my updated answer. use can use this type of parameter then use updated answer.
`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"call","params":{"db":"mohanad","l‌ogin":"mohanad@amana‌​.ps","password":"moh‌​anad123"}}`

Comment: i use your code i have this error : Print Server Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Invalid JSON data: 'db=mohanad&amp;login=mohanad%40amana.ps&amp;password=mohanad123'</p>
 AshvinGudaliya 
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: This is severed side error. you can call your web service at postman, postman gives a success result then call in the project.

Comment: adding JSONEncoding.default worked for me! thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Replace `.responseJSON` with `.responseString` so:

Instead of:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON
{ response in
      //....                
}
```

do:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseString
{ response in
     //....       
}
```

Comment: the same :( responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: @MohanadHilles You are sure you used .responseString ?!!

Comment: Your server gives 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Session expired (invalid CSRF token)</p>

Comment: yeah ,  ,,,, Print Server Error: 
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000252180 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=www.amana.club/web/session/authenticate, NSErrorFailingURLKey=www.amana.club/web/session/authenticate, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}

Comment: i am add this in header  :         let header: [String:String] = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]

Comment: What worked for me was replacing .responseJSON with .response

Comment: @AhmedElashker: 
.response mean that U are not expecting response, is simply returning void, U just expecting the response code to take action not an actual response.
Your case has nothing to do with the question asked !