# Trying to get JSON from a server, but i keep getting an error saying it's invalid

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm having a problem with my code where I'm using AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON trying to get a JSON from a server, however, I keep getting this error:

```
responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)
```

Here is my code:

```
func requestInfo() {
    let jsonURL = "..."
    
    let parameters : [String:String] = [
        "..." : "...",
        "..." : "..."
    ]
    AF.request(jsonURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON() { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(_):
            print(response.result)
            
        case .failure(_):
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

(The url and params are hidden for Private reasons)
Whenever i try a different public api it works perfectly with no errors.
However when i try to do it with my url, it just doesn't work.

**What I have tried so far:**

I've tried and done pretty much everything on the first 2 pages of Google. For Example, i have tried adding

```
encoding: URLEncoding.default
```

I have also tried adding

```
.Validate()
```

I also tried parsing my JSON in different methods like decodable.

I have been stuck on this for nearly an entire week, please help.

Comment: Try replacing `URLEncoding.default` with `JSONEncoding.default`. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738256/responseserializationfailed-with-alamofire

Comment: Have you verified whether the url gives correct response with any other tools like Postman? And is the HTTP method .get?

Comment: @gmdev i have tried that already and it didn't work.

Comment: @Jithin, when i type in the url in my browser it doesn't show anything, just an error message, however, I'm certain it works because i have seen people use this url. And yes, the url method is get.

Comment: Did you try `responseString' instead of responseJSON()? It might give you more info about the error.

Comment: Yes, I have, that also didn't seem to work, and the error is still the same.

Comment: Any chance the server returns empty JSON with response code 200?

Comment: It returns response code 400.

Comment: Do you expect empty response? Could you print full error?`case .failure(_):` => `case .failure(let error): print(error)`?

Comment: No, i don't, I'm expecting the value of the JSON, which isn't empty. I printed the full error with your code, the error is still the same.

Comment: If you have a HTTP Error 400, we can't really guess what's wrong. Any curl or POSTMAN working one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by curl or POSTMAN?

Comment: You can use postman app to test your API:  https://www.postman.com/. Please check whether you are getting the expected response with postman using your request URL and parameters.

Comment: It's telling me: 'could not send request'